# Filtered operation in odoo9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I try use filtered on recordset but in conslole get only res.partner() empty.

How get all record from res.partner where id = company_id

```
@api.multi   
def get_partner(self):
    my_ids = self.env['res.partner'].filtered(lambda r: r.id == r.company_id)
    print(my_ids)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is likely because your filter has actually filtered out all records. Meaning not one record in the set met your criteria.

You query `r.id == r.company_id` is saying

```
find all partners whose id is equal to the company id
```

So basically you need to change your lambda expression to something that will provide the list you want. If you want all partners that are part of the current users company the query would look like this.

```
company_id = self.env.user.company_id.id
my_ids = self.env['res.partner'].search([]).filtered(lambda r: r.company_id.id == company_id)
```

Comment: Sorry, just realized. Filtered only filters an existing recordset. First you need to search then filter. I updated my answer.

Comment: Phillip Stock Now work but why use filtered when with this code my_ids = self.env['res.partner'].search([('company_id','=',company_id)])  get some result. I do not understand why and where use filtered?

Comment: I think it is to be used to recycle an existing recordset. Save memory. If you had a function that used the partners recordset but a different part of your function only applied to certain partners. Rather than searching for partners a second time you could recycle the original recordset.